# melting multiple spans of variables

Tags: r

(still) new to r, and very confused as to how I should accomplish multiple melts of my data. Here is a subset:

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L
), Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("apass", 
"vpas"), class = "factor"), FreqCode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("LessVerbal", "MoreVerbal"), class = "factor"), 
Item = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 7L), Len = c(80L, 68L, 85L, 
68L, 85L, 79L), R1_1.RT = c(237L, 203L, 207L, 336L, 487L, 
340L), R1_2.RT = c(177L, 225L, 162L, 634L, 590L, 347L), R1_3.RT = c(200L, 
226L, 212L, 707L, 653L, 379L), R1.RT = c(614L, 654L, 581L, 
1677L, 1730L, 1066L), R1_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "The", class = "factor"), R1_2 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("antique", "course", "new", 
"road"), class = "factor"), R1_3 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("car", "materials", "surfaces", "technology"
), class = "factor"), R1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L), .Label = c("The antique car", "The course materials", 
"The new technology", "The road surfaces"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Subject", 
"Condition", "FreqCode", "Item", "Len", "R1_1.RT", "R1_2.RT", 
"R1_3.RT", "R1.RT", "R1_1", "R1_2", "R1_3", "R1"), class = "data.frame", row.names =  
c(NA, 
-6L))
```

My goal is to get output that (in part) looks like this:

```
Region RT WordRegion Word
R1_1.RT 237 R1_1 the
...
R1_2.RT 177 R1_2 new
...
```

EDIT: The variable ending with ".RT" (e.g., R1_1.RT) are Region names and will be melted into a Region column. The variables ending in numbers (e.g., R1_1) correspond exactly to the Region names and their associated values. I want them to be melted alongside the Region names so that I can analyze them in relation to the Region column

In the first part of the code, I melt all of the values into a Region column and change the value to RT. This seems to work fine:

```
#long transform (with individual regions at end)
SmallMelt1 = melt(df, measure.vars = c("R1_1.RT", "R1_2.RT", "R1_3.RT", "R1.RT"), var = "Region")
#change newly created column name to "RT" (note:you have to change the number in [] to match your data)
colnames(SmallMelt1)[11 ] <- "RT"
```

But I don't get how to simultaneously melt another span of variables such that they will line up vertically with the first span. I want to do something like this, after the first melt, but it does not work:

```
#Second Melt for region names (doesn't work)
SmallMelt2 = melt(SmallMelt1, measure.vars = c("R1_1", "R1_2", "R1_3", "R1"), var = "WordRegion")

#Change name to Word
colnames(SmallMelt2)[9] <- "Word" #add col number for "value" here
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification. I hope someone can help... thanks in advance - DT

Comment: It's really hard to follow what you need. Can you make the dataset smaller (not just fewer rows, but fewer columns) and give us a shorter example?

Comment: When I create your data and run your commands, SmallMelt1 is 132 obs and 34 variables and SmallMelt2 is 2904 obs and 14 variables. If you are getting 68 variables, something is wrong. I'm using function melt in package reshape. The last four columns look just like your example.

Comment: Hi. Apologies for the cluttered data. I think it is easier to read now. The variable ending with ".RT" (e.g., R1_1.RT) are Region names and will be melted into a Region column. The variables ending in numbers (e.g., R1_1) correspond exactly to the Region names and their associated values. I want them to be melted alongside the Region names so that I can analyze them in relation to the Region column. I added this note above as well. Is that more clear?  Thanks

Comment: @dcarlson. I think in the new output you will see that the WordRegion column is not lining up with the Region column. R1_1 for example, extends way past R1_1.RT.  Thanks - DT

Comment: I still haven't solved this.... any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1):

So, after consulting with someone off-list, I found the solution. My mistake was that I was trying to run the second step on the output of the first step. By running the two steps independently on the original data and then concatenating, I get the right result.

```
SmallMelt1 = melt(df, measure.vars = c("R1_1.RT", "R1_2.RT", "R1_3.RT", "R1.RT"), var =   "Region")
SmallMelt2 = melt(df, measure.vars = c("R1_1", "R1_2", "R1_3", "R1"), var = "WordRegion")
SmallMelt3=cbind(SmallMelt1,SmallMelt2[,11])
```